# CMake fails to detect dependencies

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am compiling a program using CMake with several external libraries: Qt, OMP and Boost. However recently adding fields to a class declaration in a header file results in an instant segfault when running the compiled program. This seems similar to the problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515303/qt-segmentation-fault-unless-i-rebuild) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933067/segmentation-fault-in-qt-application-framework) and just as discussed there, cleaning the build directory and recompiling does work, but unlike both of them I am not using QMake but CMake so there is no explicit dependency_dir.

I am not sure what is causing this problem and how to fix it. A temporary fix is to simply keep cleaning the build directory after changing the header, but it's not really solving the core problem.

To make extra clear what happens:

```
    vector<double> _doubletTranslationLong;       
    // This work fine

    vector<double>   _doubletTranslationLong2; 
    // if this (or anything else) is added in the header, the program 
    // compiles fine but crashes instantly for the same input that worked 
    // earlier until a clean build is done.
```

Comment: CMake is supposed to correctly handle this stuff for you. It might be that you have run into a bug. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461000/handling-header-files-dependencies-with-cmake).

Comment: You should post an excerpt of your CMake file in order to understand how your compilation process is configured.

Comment: Could you please show your cmake file?